# Slow internet connection on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: internet, connection, router, wired

I can't resolve it on my own and I can't find any usable information so far so please help me.

I have an LTE router that serves as main gate of my network, then I have the second router that bridges connection to the first one, and PC wired to the second one. The altogether network setup working fine, even with another debian based system, but Ubuntu gives me just 20Kb/s instead of regular 1Mb/s. IpV6 already disabled, DNS already set to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, is there anything else I can do? Please help, I need this to be resolved ASAP.